Help identifying movie based on one weird scene in a bowling alley
I was on a flight and as I was waiting to disembark I oversaw a scene from a movie or TV show that a guy was watching a few rows ahead of me.  The scene was sufficiently weird that I would be glad to know what film or show it came from.  Based on the production quality, I suspect the source is rather recent.  The scene is as follows:
A man has taken a girl to a bowling alley, and the girl begins marching down the lane as everyone at the alley (except for the man) claps in sync with her march. Upon reaching the end of the lane, the girl spins around, stares at the man, and does the splits. And then everyone at the alley returns to their business.
Not much to go on, sorry, but thanks for any leads.

I'd suggest the Kingpin (1996)  intro as seen here at about 1:15, but that's not a woman, and he doesn't march down the lane per say.

I'd like to personally thank you for posting this question because ever since I read the answer two months ago I've been captivated by this scene.

You're after Before I Disappear from 2014.

A troubled young man and his straight-laced niece embark on a thrilling odyssey through New York City in this heartrending drama based on an Oscar-winning short.

The short it's based on is Curfew. You can see the scene here:



